# Freeware that detects entities in pictures

Tags: gratis, images, computer-vision

I'm looking for freeware most preferably with open code that detects basic entities in pictures.

It means if I run it over a picture (gif, jpg, etc.) the system will find basic entities such as table, sky, man etc. and their location in picture.

Comment: Fair warning: this is one of the most complex and researched fields of study in software engineering: identifying elements in photos. Google started a project devoted to this, but eventually gave up. Tough stuff!

Comment: Thanks a lot where can I find papers describing the research that has already been done by Google and others?

Comment: Just found [this](https://cloud.google.com/vision/). Apparently Google didn't give up, they just repackaged it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is Image Classification software and it is available as open source as a part of deep learning with image net.  There is quite a lot of software to install so before you read any further you need to be aware that recognising portions of an image takes time - you will not be able to roll over a fresh image and have things recognised in it - instead you will need to run a classifier, preferably offline, and pre-classify your images. Also note that what you are asking for uses a lot of computer power, enough that most use it on an AWS Amazon EC2 g2.2xlarge image or better. The PyImageSearch [blog](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/18/installing-keras-for-deep-learning/) has a series of tutorials on setting up and using such a setup.

### The software

- [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is a gratis, open source, cross platform, C/C++ library for computer vision with C++, C, Python and Java interfaces.
- [Python](https://www.python.org/) is a gratis, open source, cross platform, programming language that is widely used in academic research
- Pillow is a fork of the Python Image Library, (PIL), that provided a number of helper functions - once you have python install with `pip install pillow`
- SciPy and Numpy libraries for the number punching you can install with `pip install numpy scipy
- The scipy learning library `pip install scikit-learn`
- As you will be accessing some BIG files you will need h5py so `pip install h5py`
- Theano is a Python library that allows you to define, optimize, and evaluate mathematical expressions involving multi-dimensional arrays efficiently - `pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git`
- Keras Neural Network software - `pip install keras`
- If you are running on windows you probably don't have git installed so you will need a windows build of git - there are several.
- Finally you can start from some pretrained deep learning models - `git clone https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models`

There is a tutorial on actually running this [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/08/10/imagenet-classification-with-python-and-keras/) or a number of books available.